# Issues using Python Requests to log into a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have been practicing logging into websites using requests, and for the most part I have been successful. I am currently trying to log into https://www.starbucks.com/account/signin but I can not seem to figure it out. I know that there are additional parameters to send (rememberMe, sso, reputation) and I also set the X-NewRelic-ID in the header. Not sure what else I am missing and what makes this website different from others? Any insight would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.chrome

headers = {
'Accept':'application/json',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'Content-Length':'6789',
'Content-Type':'application/json',
'Host':'www.starbucks.com',
'Origin':'https://www.starbucks.com',
'Referer':'https://www.starbucks.com/account/signin',
'User-Agent' : user_agent,
'X-NewRelic-ID':'VQUHVlNSARACUFRWDgADVA=='
}

payload = {
"username":"email@domain.com",
"password":"pass123",
"rememberMe":"true",
"sso":"false",
 "reputation":{
  "deviceFingerprint":"really-long-string",
  "platform":"Web",
  "market":"US"
 }
}

s = requests.Session()

r = s.post('https://www.starbucks.com/bff/account/signin', headers=headers, data=payload)
print (r.text)
```

Comment: You could try selenium webdriver

Comment: Well of course that will work... but I am trying to do it with requests.